# How to know three months before a yearmonth date

Tags: php, date

A date with only Year and month added together which arrives from a php function. Suppose it is 201403 or 201412. How can I get 03 months before that date using same format by php, i.e 201312 for the first one and 201409 for the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that date format is non-standard you would need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse the date. Then you can use `DateTime::modify()` to get to the date you desire.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', '201403');
$date->modify('first day of this month')->modify('-3 months');
echo $date->format('Ym');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/294693)

Comment: It would be better to reset all fields with `!` or `|`, because for example `201402` on 30th January will return March.

Answer (score 0):

Create a real date as the first of the month; make your 3 months adjustment, and return the new date formatted with just year and month

```
$yearMonth = '201403';
$date = new DateTime($yearMonth . '01');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P3M'));
echo $date->format('Ym');
```